# Is there a way to add AD groups in SharePoint online throught managed .Net CSOM code throught the Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there a way to add AD groups in SharePoint online throught managed .Net CSOM code through the name. I have found out posts doing those through Powershell but I want to do it through .Net managed code. 
eg: I have an ad group called test-group-1. I want it to be added in the members group.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory group acts as a SharePoint user, so you can user `Web.EnsureUser()` method to get/create object in SharePoint and then add it to SharePoint group.

```
using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com"))
{
    cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain.com", passowrd);

    User adGroup = cc.Web.EnsureUser("test-group-1");
    cc.Load(adGroup);

    // Grab the associted Members group for current web and add a member
    Group spGroup = cc.Web.AssociatedMemberGroup;
    spGroup.Users.AddUser(adGroup);
    cc.Load(spGroup, x => x.Users);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
}
```